# Why is there a specific negative sign in front of the $m_{12}$ term of the 2HDM Higgs potential?

Tags: particle-physics, potential, conventions, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

Why is there a specific negative sign in front of the $m_{12}$ term of the 2HDM Higgs potential?
(but not for the $m_{11}$ and $m_{22}$)

See for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0034

Eq. (2) Page 6:
$$
V = m_{11}^2\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_1 + m_{22}^2\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_2 -m_{12}^2(\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_2+\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_1) + \frac{\lambda_1}2(\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_1)^2+\frac{\lambda_2}2(\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_2)^2+\lambda_3\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_1\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_2+\lambda_4\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_2\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_1+\frac{\lambda_5}2\left[(\Phi_1^\dagger\Phi_2)^2+(\Phi_2^\dagger\Phi_1)^2\right].\tag{2}
$$

Comment: I would imagine is for symmetry breaking reason.

Comment: May you explain a bit more ?

Comment: @Davide Morgante :  you may mix yourself with the topic of SM Higgs. I'm discussing on the specific negative mass for "12", while the other "m" don't have the negative sign. The topic is not SM but BSM : 2HDM.

Comment: Please note that $m_{12}$ term is complex while $m_{11}$ and $m_{22}$ are real terms. I don't know if this has a connection with the problem of sign that I raise. Indeed, I see no imaginary part in the potential formula, so I don't see if there is a connection.

Comment: Complex? What *do* you mean? It is a real parameter, for strictly cross terms, not a mass!

Comment: Dear @Cosmas Zachos : see here https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/68445/1/MmemoireFinal.pdf page 32 : "and the complex parameters $m_{12}$, etc.". See also https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:833479/FULLTEXT01.pdf page 17 (labelled page 12) : "the remaining parameters $m_{12}$ and ...are in general complex"

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Symmetry breaking is a general topic that applies well beyond the SM. In any case, a symmetry breaking term is added lots of times in BSM theories so to connect it to the SM.

Comment: @Davide Morgante : sure, but it does not explain why $m_{11}$, $m_{22}$ have a positive sign while $m_{12}$ has a negative sign.

Comment: Your question link specifies real parameters.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos : ok, let's see if somebody has an idea on the reason of the negative sign for only a subset of the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, arbitrary signs and phases are chosen to minimize the number of explicit signs and phases that appear later, for convenience. In the paper you linked, the sign chosen for $m_{12}^2$ ensures that it appears with a positive sign in the mass terms for the charged scalars in equation (5), and with a positive sign on the diagonal elements for the mass matrix for uncharged scalars in equation (7).

Comment: thank you. Your answer is excellent. You deserve the 250 points.

Comment: Well, it seems like a cheap way for me to get 275 rep, but I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 6):

The authors are writing down the most general potential consistent with the symmetries of the problem. The constants $m_{ij}^2$ are free parameters, and the sign is purely conventional. For example, if I were to write the most general linear function of $x$, I could write $f(x)=\alpha+\beta x$ for some parameters, or $f(x)=-\alpha+\beta x$, or $f(x)=\alpha-\beta x$, etc. All these parametrizations are equivalent, as $\alpha,\beta$ are free parameters and thus I am free to define their sign however I want.

In the case at hand this freedom in choosing the parametrization becomes even more clear due to the fact that we can change the sign in front of $m_{12}^2$ by the field redefinition $\Phi_1\mapsto-\Phi_1$ (or same with $\Phi_2$), which flips the sign of $(\Phi^\dagger_1\Phi_2+\Phi^\dagger_2\Phi_1)$, but leaves the rest of the Lagrangian invariant. The sign of $m^2_{12}$ is irrelevant, as it depends on our conventions. (Note that the signs of the eigenvalues of the mass matrix don't care about the sign of $m_{12}^2$, so this sign has nothing to do with symmetry breaking!) The authors are just choosing a particular sign that they found convenient for some reason. But there is no physics behind it.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting, but it does not explain why the author has chosen (as most authors) to put specifically a negative sign for $m_{12}$ and not for the other masses. You just say "found convenient", which does not explain why it is convenient specifically for $m_{12}$, but not for the other masses.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: Hello. Ok, I contacted the author. He told that the sign negative is useful because the negative sign in the "pseudoscalar and charged masses". But for the moment, I have not seen where I can see the *proof* of this (I need to find the expression of the masses as a function of $m_{12}$)



!m_{12}^2|